# problems hooking up propane tank to grill

Tags: gas

I bought a used grill recently but when i went to hook up the propane i had an issue.

There are threads on the inside of the propane tank nozzle but its too big for the hose.

I asked the guy i bought it from an he said

> I connected the brass fitting to a lead pipe union.  That was screwed
>   onto a propane valve sticking out of the side of the house. Suggest
>   you take your picture to Home Depot or Lowes and have them give you
>   what you need.

I have a feeling he was wrong and that he had it hooked up to natural gas, but i could be wrong.

Is there a converter i need to hook up my propane tank?

[image]

UPDATE 1

one other followup question.

This is the end of the hose that hooks to the grill.  Is there a name for this fitting?  so i know what to order in terms of a new hose (for propane)
[image]

UPDATE 2

Found the manual and it says LP, which I think means propane?
[image]

Comment: Does the gas hose on this grill have the correct pressure regulator for use with a propane tank?

Comment: i suppose not.  the hose on the left goes to the grill and there is just the fitting pictured and the hose leading to the grill.

Comment: Then your guess that the guy you bought this from was running this grill from the natural gas supplied from his house is almost certainly correct. You'll need to get a new hose with a regulator to be able to use your grill with a propane tank.

Comment: you should put that last comment as an answer!   is that a pretty common hose?  you think home depot will have it?

Comment: @brhans i posted an update with a followup question, do you happen to know the name of that fitting?

Comment: @brhans, You can't just hook up a propane tank to a grill made to work with natural gas.  The gas valves have an "orifice" that the gas comes out of and that will need to be replaced as well and will be model-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear that this grill is made for, or has been converted to use natural gas rather than propane.  To convert a grill, you need two things - a new hose/regulator assembly and new gas orifices for each valve/burner.

The hose and regulator needed for a propane grill are pretty universal and easy to find.  The problem is the orifices.  This is a part that has a tiny hole in it inside the valve that allows the exact amount of gas to come out.  The orifice for natural gas is larger than propane so using the wrong orifice could result in a dangerous situation (overheating/fire).

You will need to contact the manufacturer with your grill model number to see if a conversion kit is available.  This is hit or miss - some grills have them and others don't.  I've seen super cheap grills that have kits available and very expensive ones that do not.  There is no "universal" orifice kit.

Do not attempt to run the grill on propane without the proper conversion kit.

Comment: the manual says LP Gas Grill, isnt that propane?  I have contacted the manufacturer as well for more info and about the kit.  thank you

Comment: Yes, LP = Propane.  The previous owner could have converted it to use natural gas.  You might contact him for more details or to see if he still has the propane orifices.  If it was converted then its pretty hopeful that it can be converted back.

Comment: ya its just that, he insist it was propane (not natural gas)

Answer (score 0):

i tripled checked with the guy I purchased it from and he still says it was propane; plus the manual says propane.  So with that said i believe it is, and will not be getting a conversion kit.

one of my problems was that there was another fitting I didn't notice.  It was converting the grill to use the hose that came with it (what the guy was using to hook it up to his system).  Once I removed it, i was able to use a standard propane hose!

His propane system must have used natural gas fittings.

Comment: Bizarre, but OK... Glad things are working.