# Best way to connect my 3/8 propane grill to home natural gas? They’re different sizes

Tags: natural-gas, propane

I’m having issues connect my 3/8propane grill QUICK CONNECT to my home QUICK CONNECT. I can’t find a adapter nor figure out the size of my home line off the house which is bigger. The serial number of the home line quick connects is ANDI Z21.41 / csa 6.9.

I need to figure out the size of that serial number than a quick connect adapter which I’m having trouble doing. Please help.

Comment: Would see this question and see the problems are more than just an adapter.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/222509/switching-propane-bbq-to-natural-gas?rq=1

Comment: Believe it or not, propane (i.e. LPG) and natural gas (NG) are not the same thing.  Unless you grill is specifically labelled for either, using NG in an LPG appliance is both dangerous and in many places illegal.

Comment: They are different specifically to prevent you from doing *"the wrong thing"* as you are trying to do. Pressures and fuel/air ratios are **very different** between propane & natural gas - even convertible "dual-fuel" grills **need to be converted** (typically an orifice change) to use the other fuel.

Comment: Look at the manual to see if there is a conversion kit available for your grill or a customer support phone number where you can ask if there is a kit to convert from LPG to NG.

Comment: Just FYI... if you do convert it you are looking at a much lower temperature on your grill given the insides of the grill stays the same.

Comment: Does your house run on _Propane_ or _Natural Gas_? Some folks who live in the country do have a large _Propane_ tank in the yard that's used for heating and hot water, so this isn't _necessarily_ a (potentially dangerous) conversion project.